# Image show after 100% download

Tags: css, image, loading

While Loading[image]

After Load[image]

i want to show image after 100% load. any css ??

Comment: you'd want to use javascript for this case

Comment: can you please share code if you have

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
img{display:none;}
```

and js:

```
$('img').load(function () { $(this).show(); });
```